# EditText focus on drawable click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` with a `drawableRight`. The problem is that when I click the drawable, the `EditText` is in this weird mode where it is not exactly focused. Below is how it looks:

[image]

I know its not focused because below is how it looks when its focused:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that when the drawable is clicked, the EditText should not gain focus. I tried `myEditText.clearFocus()` in the `onTouchListener` when I do stuff when the drawable is clicked, but of no use. I am not clear on whats wrong and hence cannot figure out what should I try.

Comment: What should happen when drawable is pressed? This does not make sense that one view affects another, if the they are not related somehow in XML AND if uppon touching drawable, does not trigger any movement of drawable.

Comment: I show a custom view when its pressed. I left it out of the question because thats not the problem. I can inflate my view correctly when the drawable is clicked. The problem is that the EditText _thinks_ its focused? I'm confused because its not even completely focused.

Comment: Have you tried worst-case stuff, like unplugging device you use from computer, deleting the App completely and then re-plug it. Do a Clean Build on Project and again Run. I am just assuming these stuff, since I too cannot understand the behaviour of EditText, if its really not manipulated per code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `EditText` is `isPressed()` or not in your first scenario. I had this issue a while back where the `EditText` was in a similar state as you described and I was checking all the time for `isFocused()` which was `false` but `isPressed()` was `true`. All I needed to do was in the `onTouchListener` set `pressed` to false i.e. `myEditText.setPressed(false)`.

Comment: this was it! setting `onPressed` to false did work. do you know why does it happen though?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting an `onTouchListener`?

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (editComment.getRight() - editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, thats how I am implementing the way my custom view is shown when the drawable is clicked.

Comment: how it wil be written for left drawable?